# renv + venv + jupyterlab + IRkernel: will it blend?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, renv, rprofile

## Short version

What is the simple and elegant way to use `renv`, `venv` and `jupyterlab` with `IRkernel` together? In particular, how to automatically activate `renv` from jupyter notebook that is not in the root directory?

## Long version

I'm embracing a "polyglot" data science style, which means using both python and R in tandem. Now `venv` is awesome, and `renv` is awesome, and `jupyterlab` is awesome, so I'm trying to figure out what is the neat way to use them all together.

I *almost* have it, so probably a few hints would be enough to finish this setup. Here's where I'm at.

### System

Start with a clean OS, and install system level requirements: R + renv and Python + venv. For example on Ubuntu it would be approximatelly like that:

```sh
# R
sudo apt install r-base
sudo R -e "install.packages('renv')"

# Python
sudo apt install python3.8
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
```

### Project

Now create a bare bones project `jupyrenv` with two files:

```
jupyrenv/
├── DESCRIPTION
└── requirements.txt
```

`DESCRIPTION` contains R dependencies:

```
Suggests:
    IRkernel,
    fortunes
```

`requirements.txt` contains python dependencies:

```
jupyterlab
```

Create virtual environments and install dependencies (order matters, R has to follow python):

```sh
# Python
python3.8 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt

# R
R -e "renv::init(bare=TRUE)"
R -e "renv::install()"
R -e "IRkernel::installspec()"
```

Very neat so far!

### Jupyter

launch jupyter from the command line and rejoice, it works!

```
jupyter-lab
```

[image]

### What's not to like?

Unfortunatelly, if I create a folder (say `notebooks`) and launch an R notebook there, it
does not work :(

```
[I 2022-02-23 19:07:24.628 ServerApp] Creating new directory in 
[I 2022-02-23 19:07:31.159 ServerApp] Creating new notebook in /notebooks
[I 2022-02-23 19:07:31.416 ServerApp] Kernel started: 0aa2c276-18dc-4511-b308-e78234fa71d4
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘IRkernel’
Calls: :: ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
```

### Attempt to fix

It seems that `renv` is not used from a subfolder, so we need to hint the `R` process to use it. I tried to add an extra `.Rprofile` file the `notebooks` subfolder:

```
jupyrenv/
├── DESCRIPTION
├── requirements.txt
├── renv
├── venv
├── notebooks
│   ├── .Rprofile
│   └── Untitled.ipynb
├── .Rprofile
└── Untitled.ipynb
```

With the following contents:

`.Rprofile`:

```
source("../renv/activate.R")
```

And it *kind of* works, but not really. First, when trying to create an R notebook in the `notebooks` directory, it creates a new `renv`:

```
[I 2022-02-23 19:22:28.986 ServerApp] Creating new notebook in /notebooks
[I 2022-02-23 19:22:29.298 ServerApp] Kernel started: b40a88b3-b0bb-4839-af45-85811ec3073c
# Bootstrapping renv 0.15.2 --------------------------------------------------
* Downloading renv 0.15.2 ... OK (downloaded source)
* Installing renv 0.15.2 ... Done!
* Successfully installed and loaded renv 0.15.2.
```

Then that instance of jupyter works, and I can use it, but if I restart, it stops working and get's back to the missing `IRkernel` error:

```
[I 2022-02-23 19:24:58.912 ServerApp] Kernel started: 822d9372-47fd-43f5-8ac7-77895ef124dc
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘IRkernel’
Calls: :: ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
```

What am I missing?

Comment: R essentially doesn’t cope *at all* with a project structure based on nested folders. Neither base R, nor the package structure nor ‘renv’ know how to handle this. They all essentially expect a completely flat structure without hierarchy. This is a major shortcoming of R. (My package [‘box’](https://klmr.me/box/) allows creating nested folder-based projects but unfortunately this won’t help you since it doesn’t address the ‘renv’ configuration.)

Comment: Oh my, I was looking for something like `box::use` for hours! This goes into my `DESCRIPTION` right now  Sad to hear about the folders, though :(

Comment: Does it have to only be on your machine? You can use JupyterLab, with R or Python kernels, or RStudio in launches from [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/r-conda). Choose the appropriate launch button. You can actually switch interfaces once you launch the session. There's some tricks to using the URL in the address bar. For example, from RStudio to JupyterLab, you change the end of the address from `/rstudio` to `/lab`. You can use that as a template for your repos and add what you want so you don't then need renv or venv. Binderhubs, the basis, can be deployed on your local system.

Comment: Thanks, but I would really prefer a "barebones" solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened this question as an [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/946) in the `renv` github repo, and maintainers kindly provided a workaround. The contents of the `notebooks/.Rprofile` should be as follows:

```sh
owd <- setwd(".."); source("renv/activate.R"); setwd(owd)
```

It blends!